# Mongo Aggregation to Calculate Unique IDs in Returned Docs is Slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In addition to returning a filtered set of documents to the end user via a Mongo view, I also have a couple functions running to generate running totals. For some reason though, while my `find()` operation is really fast (225ms), this additional aggregation I'm running takes over 6 seconds to perform -- which slows down the whole endpoint, because this data is passed on in what I'm returning.

I'm trying to understand why this aggregation would be so slow? This aggregation matches to the filters passed in by the end-user, and then calculates the number of unique customer ids that appear in the returned documents. This is what it looks like:

```
  let totalCustomers = await db
    .collection("view_accounts_report")
    .aggregate([{
        $match: search
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          customers: {
            $addToSet: "$customer._id"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          uniqueCustomers: {
            $size: "$customers"
          }
        }
      }
    ])
    .next();
```

Why would this take 6 seconds to run? Any ideas? Any tips on how I can speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it'll definitely take some time, if there's a lot of distinct users (or a lot users in general). If you want to check, why it's taking so much time, try the [`explain` argument](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation).

On the other hand, [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html) *might* be a better choice here:

```
let customers = await db.collection('view_accounts_report').distinct(search);
let totalCustomers = customers.length;
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that. And `distinct` actually takes twice as long to return the same data :).

Comment: So is 6 seconds not completely unreasonable to return this query when searching on a view containing 8,000 docs? Also, I have tried the `explain('executionStats')` argument, and it tells me the index from the targeted collection is being used. So it's unclear to me why this is so slow.

Comment: Can you maybe post the explain result above? It'll help definitely.

Comment: I meant using explain on aggregate, like this: `db.collection('...').aggregate([...], {explain: true})`.

Comment: One thing you can definitely do is getting rid of `$exists`, when `$gt` is used: there's no single value, which may pass `$gt` and fail `$exists`. Second, and the **most** important, is that most of the evaluation time is took on the aggregation above, so the view definition.

Comment: Good point on `$exists`. Got rid of that. As to your second point on evaluation time, where are looking to see that specifically?

Comment: In general, such aggregations (and distinct) are very fast queries - in your case, three `$lookup`s and a lot of other phases are taking the most time here. You can test it, by running the same aggregation, without last two phases (so the `$group` and `$project`) and call `.toArray()` instead - simple `find` is returning first few results but the `$group` needs all of them

Comment: Thanks, @Radoslow. So, if one needs to do multiple look-ups and other such stages in an aggregation pipeline like this when shaping a Mongo view, is it inevitable that it's going to be slow? Are there no recommended ways around this? What, if any, alternatives exist in crafting the same data?

Comment: Well, `$lookup`s may be optimised too - check if your `foreignField` are indexed (they are in your case, as it's `_id`) and run only _heads_ (prefixes of the pipeline) to check, where's the bottleneck. In your very case, it might be a good idea to aggregate the original collection and _probably_ (I don't know your case good enough) get rid of part of these steps (maybe there's unnecessary field, etc.).

Comment: Also, in Postman, if I just run the main aggregation, without also getting the results of `count` and `totalCustomers`, the query is very fast -- like 300ms. So I'm trying to reconcile that with you're saying about the aggregation steps being the problem. By commenting out the code I run for "count" and "totalCustomers" I see the query that used to take 6 seconds to run reduced to just 300ms.

Comment: Go on then - benchmark your aggregation step by step to find out, where's the bottlenect exactly. If running the same query (only the `$match` phase) and getting all results is _fast_, then it might be the `$group` itself. // I think I've answered your question, huh?

Comment: Could it be that because I'm passing a `skip` and a `limit` for the main `view_accounts_report` query, that this returns quickly, but queries like for `count` and `totalCustomers` take much longer because they need to read all documents?

Comment: Definitely. That's exactly what I meant about returning earlier/only part of the result.

Comment: And by the way, I think it also answers your another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023885/how-to-speed-up-count-on-mongodb-view).